# Trying to compile Jasper Reports in Eclipse without Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I'm trying to do a project with Jasper Reports but when I try to run my project compiler says:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/ReferenceMap

I added those jars to my build path:

- commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
- commons-collections4-4.0.jar
- commons-digester3-3.2.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- jasperreports-5.6.0.jar
- jasperreports-applet-5.6.0.jar
- jasperreports-fonts-5.6.0.jar
- jasperreports-javaflow-5.6.0.jar

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [javadocs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/ReferenceMap.html) ReferenceMap for v4 of commons collection is in package org/apache/commons/**collections4**/map and not in org/apache/commons/**collections**/map

Can you check if this version of commons collections works with your implementation?

Comment: If I enter inside of commons-collections4-4.0.jar I can see:   commons-collections4-4.0.jar\org\apache\commons\collections4\map so don't know why Eclipse can't find it ...

Comment: Eclipse is trying to find org/apache/commons/collections/map (not collections4). Can you try including commons collections 3.2.1 ?

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem. I also had to do the same trick with digester jar but I don't know why I need to use old jars anyway ...

Comment: Its possible that some of the jars in your application are not compatible with the newer versions of the other jars